# How to reformat this array without knowing the keys in advance

Tags: php, arrays

I'm querying an API and getting a response back with various countries. Here is the relevant array I'm working with and what it prints out.

```
    print_r($apiResponse['response']['data'][0]['countries']);
```

prints this:

> Array ( [US] => Array ( [id] => 840 [code] => US [name] => United States [regions] => Array ( ) ) [CA] => Array ( [id] => 124 [code] => CA [name] => Canada [regions] => Array ( ) ) )

I am looking to save an array of only the two character country codes from that data. The only thing is the key is unknown to me when I query it so I don't know how to access the [code] section of it to save it to my new array.

I want to end up being able to take whatever amount of countries the API sends back and save the two character codes in a format like this:

```
'country_codes' => array('US','CA','UK','AU')
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `$countryCodes = array_keys($myComplexCountryArray);` or `$countryCodes = array_column($myComplexCountryArray, 'code');`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-keys.php

Comment: @mark-baker array_keys works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `array_keys()` function. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) you have the documentation.